# Grouping algorithm for text similarity

Tags: nlp, similarity, cosine-similarity, linguistics

So i'm working on a project, based on the grouping algorithm by Chali in his "Document Clustering with Grouping and Chaining Algorithms" research paper.

I've gotten to section 4.1. I'm trying to understand in the in the context of finding articles about the same topic, what is meant by the clusters overlapping?

I've identified the cosine similarity score between articles. e.g.

So say article x is a guardian article

{

article 1 - cnn article 0.1 cosine score (no threshold) when compared to article x

article 2 - cnn article cosine 0.8 cosine score (inserted into high threshold cluster ) when compared to article x

article 3 - cnn article cosine 0.5 cosine score (inserted into low threshold cluster) when compared to article x

}

My question is, have I identified the clusters correctly? Could I e.g. mix stories from other publishers into this cluster?

And when the article says "If not more than 2 texts are overlapping with the final clusters, then we take this group as a final cluster". Interpreting this is also very difficult for me as like I said i'm not sure what 'overlapping' means.

Thanks for the help!